# Cannot see all my open tabs during Alt + Tab

Tags: windows, tabs, alt

Before when i was using **Alt + Tab** I could see all the open tabs and adjust accordingly. Now suddenly my computer seems to not want to allow me to preview my tabs. What did I do to cause this and how can I fix it?

Btw when I mean 'preview'  the tabs it wasn't aero-peek it was just a show of all the open tabs in 2D, I don't know if there is a word for it.

I already tried to check settings and multitasking, but I don't know what I am looking for.

Comment: Go to Settings, Personalization, Taskbar settings and enable / disable "Use Peek".  See if that helps.  Also, just hover over the taskbar icons as that shows a small preview.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's called 'task switcher'.

Comment: What version of Windows?